# Discord.py bot is missing permission?

Tags: discord.py

I tried to do an autorole system for my discord bot and my code looks like that:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "#", intents = intents)
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    server_name = client.get_guild(802985801100165200)
    await member.send(f'Willkommen auf {server_name}!')
    print(1)
    rolle = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Member')
    await member.add_roles(rolle)
```

I get this as an error:

```
    Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wenze\PycharmProjects\discordbotproject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wenze\PycharmProjects\discordbotproject\main.py", line 34, in on_member_join
    await member.add_roles(rolle)
  File "C:\Users\wenze\PycharmProjects\discordbotproject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 777, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\wenze\PycharmProjects\discordbotproject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Comment: if you don't have the menage roles perm you cant give roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is either

1. The bot doesn't have the `Manage Roles` permissions

   - To fix this just reinvite your bot with the correct permissions.
2. The role that the bot is trying to give is above the bot in hierarchy.

You can handle this error by using a try except block looking like:

```
try:
    Member.add_roles(role)
except discord.Forbidden:
    # This will be triggered when the bot has incorrect permissions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hei
I have had that issue too with my node.js bot, where I could not give roles to any of my server's members.

I kicked the bot out of the server, I went in this page [here](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html) and gave my bot all permissions (for simplicity I marked every checkbox). I then copied my bot Client ID and pasted in the required field. I pressed the link at the bottom of the page to call it back into my server. That fixed my issue